# Project specific "Object reference not set to an instance of an object System.NullReferenceException" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

First of all this is my first post ! haha so please be patient with me as i learn,

Let me explain whats going on.

basically i wanted replicate this project

https://www.hackster.io/peejster/facial-recognition-security-system-c6ca6c

So based on what he said i signed up a Microsoft Cognitive Service and i have have been using the free facial recognition API, and stored the key in the constants folder. i also removed Application Insights as the creator said that it isn't included.

so when i tried to Debug/Publish the code i get this error message:

[image: Message]

"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

i did take note of the Prerequisites and i have checked that all are compatible

This is the list of hardware im using if it helps

RP Pi 2 Model B plus Grove shield

Motion Sensor Board(PIR Sensor)

the output is set to GPIO 4

Prolink Webcam Model No: PCC5020

If anyone has a solution please do get back to me :) thanks in advance!

Hope this is specific enough :)

Comment: In the pic you posted, the error is "Value does not fall within the expected range".  Post the code that's causing the issue. Also, stop by [help] and read [ask].

Comment: When I click Intruders area before the Intruders area images are initialized, I get the same error message as you. The exception is thrown when the intruder images are added or deleted while intruder visitor is enumerated in intruder visitors list. However, reading intruder visitors list is not thread safety when it is changed by another thread. The thread security mechanism could be added into project like locking and event handling. You can follow this introduction to try to use AsyncLock in UpdateIntruderVisitors() function, then the intruder visitor list can be enumerated normally.

Comment: Link:
 [AsyncLock](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock)
and [Instruction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/)